# jQuery ~ Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to call my javascript function on click:

```
<div id='alert'><button onclick='alertClose()' class='alert'>Close</button></div>
```

Here is the function:

```
function alertClose(){
    $("#alert").animate({
        left: "107%"
    });
}
```

EDIT: The console keeps saying that there is no function called alertClose

Comment: What is your question? What errors do you see?

Comment: What does it do instead of working?:) Any error messages? Is the function called, but not doing what you want, or not called at all?

Comment: here is the website: https://chat-trial-silverneon123-2.c9.io/ 
The alert is in the bottom right, and the button is what im having problems with

Comment: You need to improve the question instead of adding a link that won't be available for other people to reproduce the issue later

Comment: Your function isn't anywhere on that page

Comment: it seems the url of javascript file is wrong , check it

Comment: My guess is this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined  is causing your js to fail.  Just a thought.  Also, if you are using jquery, why not do: $("#alert button").click(alertClose); instead of declaring it in the html.

Comment: @ShaunakD the alertClose() is defined in navbar.js

Comment: New Link: https://chat-trial-silverneon123-2.c9.io/js/navbar.js

Comment: `alertClose()` isn't in global namespace . You have a simple scope issue. Please post code in question .. not as expernal link since links rot

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post what I think is your issue:

First, you are getting a js error in ajax.js here:

```
var room = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0].innerHTML;
```

the document.getElements call is returning nothing and failing

Then, you need to adjust your code to use jquery and not inline events:

HTML:

```
<div id='alert'><button class='alert'>Close</button></div>
```

JS:

```
function alertClose(){
    $("#alert").animate({
        left: "107%"
    });
}
 $("#alert button").click(alertClose);
```

Try that out and see how it works.  Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/btqztdgd/8/)

Edit: removed inline function left by mistake

Comment: you left inline event so function will fire twice

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it.

Answer (score -4):

call the function

```
function alertClose();
```